# A generalization of the Diophantine $m$-tuple problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Are there distinct positive integers $a_1，a_2，a_3，b_1，b_2，b_3$ such that $a_ib_j+1$ is a perfect square number for each $i,j$ ($1\leq i,j\leq3$)?

I asked the following question in a group, and someone [asked it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622495/how-do-you-solve-this-problem-of-square-numbers) on MathStackExchange, but there aren't any answers after 5 months. After some research, I think the problem is very hard, so I ask it here.

At first I tried to find solutions. I wrote a C++ program. It shows that the largest number among such $a$ and $b$ must exceed 50000. Then I tried to find positive integer points on the elliptic curve
$$
y^2=(a_1x+1)(a_2x+1)(a_3x+1).
$$ For some small $a_1,a_2,a_3$, there are at most two positive integer points on the curve. So I think such $a$ and $b$ don't exist.

Next, I found the problem similar to the Diophantine sextuple problem, but $a_ia_j+1$ and $b_ib_j+1$ can be squared. I read [this webpage about Diophantine $m$-tuples](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/dtuples.html) by Dujella and some papers about it, but they all require $a_ia_j+1$ to be a square number, so cannot be extended to this problem.

Does someone know the answer or related works?

Comment: I've computationally verified that if a solution exists, then at least one of the numbers must be $>10^7$.